# How to find which files are served by Node server?

Tags: node.js, web-services, server, process

I am able to hit the route of a node server:

e.g. `https://myserver.com/dashboard/myroute`

Then I am able to connect to `myserver`. After I connect to it - how to see where exactly is Node running from above webpage and routes?

Looking for nodejs process and also files that are being served..

Comment: Are you using express? (a demo/example and code snippets would help immensely)

Comment: Is this code you've written or a website that you are trying to inspect?

Comment: It is a legacy code and the guy went on vacation so trying to figure out where / what is running on a server..

Comment: But if you have the code you can look for the routes.... https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html Routes are defined by the developer.